# How could I use count() with Q object?

Tags: django, django-q

I'm using Django, how should I use the query using Q object from django.db.models along with count()?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Given using a filter will result in a queryset object, you should just be able to use count() on the end of said containing filter. Like:

```
count = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(my_field__startswith='Hello')).count()
```